# How to "source" a shell file in C?

Tags: c, shell

I have one C program and one shell script and I'd like to "source" shell script using my C.

I tried use *system()* function, after it I can run script properly, but my colors doesn't work. 
For example instead of CYAN - I defined it as:

```
CYAN='\e[96m'
```

it shows only ***\e[96m*** and some functions just failed with message:

```
./myscript.sh: 27: [: y: unexpected operator
```

Is there some solution?

Comment: Problems with your terminal settings? Does your script work correctly standalone?

Comment: note: "sourcing" in this context makes no sense. Do you want to *execute* the script?

Comment: Could you be more specific? When I source shell script normally from terminal "source ./myscript.sh" everything works properly. Yes, I want execute the script. But like: ". ./script.sh" or "source ./script.sh", using C program.

Comment: By "sourcing" you seem to mean the shell's builtin command that reads a file and execute the commands therein within the same process.  That makes sense only when the process performing it is, in fact, the shell.

Answer (score 2):

A program that is not itself the shell cannot "source" a file of shell commands as the shell itself can do.  A program can run such a file as a script, either directly or by invoking a shell to run it, but the script then gets its own environment, and any changes it applies to that environment do not propagate to the parent process's environment.

Programs receive their environment as a function of program startup.  If you want a variable to be set in a program's environment then by far the easiest thing to do is arrange for it to be set when the program is invoked, either by exporting it from the parent process's environment or by wrapping program launch in a script that arranges for the same.  There are additional alternatives on the process startup side, as well.

If a C program wants to alter its environment *after* startup, then it can use the `setenv()` and `unsetenv()` functions.  Those are defined by POSIX, not C itself, but if we're talking about sourcing shell commands then it seems reasonable to assume a POSIX context.

Additionally, if you are trying to define `CYAN` as a shell variable whose contents are an ANSI escape sequence, then your syntax is wrong.  No escape sequences at all are recognized within ordinary single quotes (even closing single quote cannot be escaped).  Within double quotes the backslash does function as an escape character, but in a strict sense: C-style character codes are not supported there.  If, again, you're processing that in the shell, as opposed to in C, then you appear to want

```
CYAN=$'\e[96m'
```

(Note the `$`, which is essential for `\e` to be recognized as representing the "escape" character, and which causes the shell to recognize a few other C-style escape sequences as well.)

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that. So in other words it's impossible? And I must use functions such as setenv(), unsetenv().

Comment: @Yeez, it is impossible for any process to modify a different process's environment, except inasmuch as a parent process controls the *initial* environment of any child process it spawns.  The C implementation of the shell itself uses `setenv()` to handle variable assignments such as you asked about.

Comment: Ok, so now comes the time to rewrite it into C. Thanks alot for your time and nice explanation.